# Is this state machine correct for a Mealy 4b'1001 sequence detector?

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines, sequence-detector

Is this a correct state machine diagram for detecting the 4-bit sequence 4b'1001 using a non-overlapping Mealy FSM? If any bit is out of sequence, reset to the initial state. Once the last bit of the sequence is received, the output should be set to 1 and return to looking for the first bit and wait for the next "1." Not using the last 1 as the first 1. If not, I need an explanation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the FSM diagram is correct for detecting the non-overlapping sequence **1001**.

To demonstrate that the diagram is correct, you can run this [Verilog simulation on EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/W3Bg).  It shows several example input data streams, but you can change the input sequence to whatever you want.

Here is an example waveform:

[image]